# Handling the String with <> characters

Tags: apex, string, richtextarea, long-text-area

I am trying to convert the Long Area Text in to the RTF Field, the long text area sometime has the the <> in between the texts which is treated as a markup. I tried below to escape the characters like below

```
        newArticle.Article_Body_Long_T__c = result.SolutionNote;
        String rep = newArticle.Article_Body_Long_T__c.replaceAll('<', '\<');
        rep = newArticle.Article_Body_Long_T__c.replaceAll('>', '\>');
        newArticle.SOP_Article_Body__c = rep.replaceAll('\n', '<br/>');
```

But it throws error like `Illegal string literal: Invalid string literal '\<'. Illegal character sequence \<' in string literal.` I want the <> braces retained in the RTF and cannot replace them with the '' empty string. Please let me how I can I handle this

Comment: Can you add an example value for `result.SolutionNote` to the question that replicates the problem?

Comment: Also, by "RTF Field", I assume you mean "Rich Text Area Field"?

Comment: why not just replace `<` with `&lt;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` character is an escape character in Apex. If you wanted it to be a literal backslash in the resulting string, you'd have to double up on it: `\\`. However, this won't work the way you expect, as the characters need to be escaped in HTML. Use `escapeHtml4()` to do this:

```
    newArticle.Article_Body_Long_T__c = result.SolutionNote.escapeHtml4();
```

Or, to remove them entirely:

```
    newArticle.Article_Body_Long_T__c = result.SolutionNote.stripHtmlTags();
```

Note that if `<br/>` is used, you'll lose the line breaks in the resulting text, so you may need to do additional replacements.